# What does "caffeinated" mean in context of "dripcap"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> [dripcap](https://github.com/dripcap/dripcap) - Caffeinated Packet Analyzer

In [a dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caffeinated):

> Full Definition of caffeinated
>
> 1
>      :  stimulated by or as if by caffeine
>
> 2
>      :  containing caffeine

Software doesn't contain and is not stimulated by caffeine. Is there some third slang meaning of "caffeinated" in relation to technology, like "feature-rich" or "very fast"?

Comment: Yes it probably means "very fast" seeing as it's a packet analyser, but I;m not familiar with dripcap specifically. As an analogy, in slang, people have used the terms "leaded" and "unleaded" to mean "full" strength or "light".

Comment: stimulated by  **or as if**  by caffeine  (emphasis added)

Comment: I don't know of any slang meaning, but I did notice it contains CoffeeScript: https://github.com/dripcap/arp/  I'm not really sure that's why it's "caffeinated", though.